# property decorator initialization in python

Tags: python, properties, decorator, dependency-properties

***I was wondering if anyone knew if there are any subtle differences in using `@property` and a regular property?***

Are there any problems that may occur with initialization for a property when using the `@property` decorator in python?
It is my understanding that this decorator allows for a property to be calculated by a function everytime it is called since it is a property which depends on other mutable properties.
I have written some of these `@property` decorators in, but they are not working for some reason. 
I recieve this form of an error:

`for key in temp_spectra.overall_properties_dictionary:`

`AttributeError: 'Spectra' object has no attribute 'overall_properties_dictionary'`

As I understand it, the correct way for creating these `@property`s is like so:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class someObject(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def some_other_property(self):
        # some complicated function which will recalculate everytime it is called
        # because the other properties may be mutable
        p = self.x + self.y
        return p
class otherObject(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, someObject):
        print someObject.some_other_property

otherObject(someObject(1,5))
```

However, this works! So I'm not certain which part of my code could be causing this.
It is worth mentioning that I am in the process of converting my code to utilize `multiprocessing`.  Could this cause problems? I just don't understand what could be going wrong with the initialization to cause this type of error.

**EDIT: I changed the code to match the new-style class as suggested.***

Comment: `@property` properties are not irregular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing worth noting is that properties are only supported for new-style classes, which yours isn't.

Change

```
class someObject:
```

to

```
class someObject(object):
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize there were such things as new and old style classes.  My main program does have inheratance however.  The object which is throwing the error that says it doesn't have the property is an `QtCore.QObject` object, while the object which aggregates and calls this object is an `QtGui.QTabWidget` object.

Comment: I changed the code, but it still works in that example, while it still does not work in my main program. Does the new-style / old-style class difference really cause problems with the properties?

Comment: @chase: Yes it can. As to your main problem, I am not sure.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will keep searching for any other subtle differences which could cause initialization problems.